# Trigger function only if no mouse clicks in x seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following project: https://sporedev.ro/pleiade/lobby.html (ignore the sounds, they will not autoplay in the future)

I am highlighting the clickable area maps from time to time using JS like this:

```
function blinkIn() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("#map area").filter(':eq(0), :eq(1), :eq(2), :eq(3), :eq(4), :eq(5), :eq(6), :eq(7), :eq(8), :eq(9), :eq(10), :eq(11), :eq(12), :eq(13), :eq(14)').trigger("mouseenter.mapify").trigger("focus.mapify").trigger("touchend.mapify");
        $(".mapify-svg polygon").filter(':eq(0), :eq(1), :eq(2), :eq(3), :eq(4), :eq(5), :eq(6), :eq(7), :eq(8), :eq(9), :eq(10), :eq(11), :eq(12), :eq(13), :eq(14)').css("stroke", "#FFF").css('opacity', '0.5').css('stroke-dasharray', '50').css('stroke-dashoffset', '100').css('animation', 'dash 1.5s linear forwards');
        blinkOut();
      }, 3000);
    }

    function blinkOut() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("#map area").filter(':eq(0), :eq(1), :eq(2), :eq(3), :eq(4), :eq(5), :eq(6), :eq(7), :eq(8), :eq(9), :eq(10), :eq(11), :eq(12), :eq(13), :eq(14)').trigger('mouseout.mapify');
        $(".mapify-svg polygon").filter(':eq(0), :eq(1), :eq(2), :eq(3), :eq(4), :eq(5), :eq(6), :eq(7), :eq(8), :eq(9), :eq(10), :eq(11), :eq(12), :eq(13), :eq(14)').css("stroke", "").css('opacity', '').css('stroke-dasharray', '').css('stroke-dashoffset', '').css('animation', '');;
        blinkIn();
      }, 1500);
    }

    blinkIn();
```

I did some research on SO on how to prevent the function to run if mouse clicks are detected. I found out about `mousedown` and the other states but it didn't seemed to help me.

```
document.body.getElementsByTagName("*").onclick = function(){ clearTimeout; };
```

How can I trigger the `blinkIn` function only if there are no mouse clicks in x seconds?

Comment: The `function(){ clearTimeout; }` part couldn't have worked in a fiddle, because `clearTimeout` is a function - you have to pass it the id of the timeout that you want to clear (which is the value returned by `setTimeout()`).

Comment: I meant the last line of code. Here's the test: https://jsfiddle.net/d7wzp5z7/

Comment: And... you're right. It didn't worked, sorry. 04:48AM here. Had the impression that it works, will edit the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try this? (Not tested though)

```
var timeout;
function blinkIn() {
   timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    $("#map area").filter(':eq(0), :eq(1), :eq(2), :eq(3), :eq(4), :eq(5), :eq(6), :eq(7), :eq(8), :eq(9), :eq(10), :eq(11), :eq(12), :eq(13), :eq(14)').trigger("mouseenter.mapify").trigger("focus.mapify").trigger("touchend.mapify");
    $(".mapify-svg polygon").filter(':eq(0), :eq(1), :eq(2), :eq(3), :eq(4), :eq(5), :eq(6), :eq(7), :eq(8), :eq(9), :eq(10), :eq(11), :eq(12), :eq(13), :eq(14)').css("stroke", "#FFF").css('opacity', '0.5').css('stroke-dasharray', '50').css('stroke-dashoffset', '100').css('animation', 'dash 1.5s linear forwards');
    blinkOut();
  }, 3000);
}

function blinkOut() {
   setTimeout(function() {
    $("#map area").filter(':eq(0), :eq(1), :eq(2), :eq(3), :eq(4), :eq(5), :eq(6), :eq(7), :eq(8), :eq(9), :eq(10), :eq(11), :eq(12), :eq(13), :eq(14)').trigger('mouseout.mapify');
    $(".mapify-svg polygon").filter(':eq(0), :eq(1), :eq(2), :eq(3), :eq(4), :eq(5), :eq(6), :eq(7), :eq(8), :eq(9), :eq(10), :eq(11), :eq(12), :eq(13), :eq(14)').css("stroke", "").css('opacity', '').css('stroke-dasharray', '').css('stroke-dashoffset', '').css('animation', '');;
    blinkIn();
  }, 1500);
}

blinkIn();
$(document).click(function(){
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  blinkIn();
});
```

Pass to a variable the `setTimeout` then when the user clicks just use `clearTimeout` in the variable.

Comment: @SporeDev here is the update [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d7wzp5z7/1/) try to look at that.. its just the same concept above..

Comment: Still no change with my code. Any idea why? I can see it working in the fiddle.

Comment: @SporeDev try `document.getElementById('id_of_the_element').onclick` in your code..

Comment: That seems to disable it but it doesn't enables it back after x number of seconds without a click (it stops calling the function permanently). Other than that it doesn't work if I put the id of the image map there so that any clicks on the image map prevents the function. I have to add an id to all of the areas and that still wouldn't cover clicks outside those areas.

Comment: @SporeDev add `blinkIn();` inside the onclick after `clearTimeout`. Look at the code above. I updated it. so it will reset.

Comment: It works now, thank you! Is there any way so that I can trigger this behaviour when a user clicks anywhere? Not only on a particular ID since I can't use the map id it seems.

Comment: @SporeDev anywhere in the page? you can use `$(document).click(function(e) { clearTimeout(timeout);
  blinkIn(); });`

Comment: Yes, anywhere in the page.

Comment: It works now. Thank you very much for having patience with me. You're a life-saver (learned some JS in the process as well). :)